# How to prevent selecting of children once it's parent is selected?

Tags: javascript, jstree

I want to disable the children nodes automatically when a parent node is selected. How could I achieve this in jstree?

```
.on('select_node.jstree', function(e, data)
{
    console.log("$$$$$$$$$");
    obj = data.instance.get_node(data.node.id, true);
    if (obj.parentsUntil('.jstree','li').children('a.jstree-clicked').length ||         obj.children('ul').find('a.jstree-clicked:eq(0)').length){
    data.instance.deselect_node(obj);
    }
});
```

I used this code but couldn't find any result. Please do help me out with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `data.node.children` to get the children of the node. Or you can use `data.node.children_d` to get all children, even the children of the children.

Here is an example how to iterate through all children:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.node.children_d.length; i++) {
  //for example disable node
  $(\'#jstree_demo_div\').jstree(true).disable_node(data.node.children_d[i]);
}
```

Hope that helps!